# Fresh install of MacTeX 2020. Fatal error When typesetting minimal ConTeXt file

Tags: luatex, context, mactex, compilation-error, minimal

I just installed MacTeX on mac.

created the code below code in TeXShop:

```
\starttext
minimal ConTeXt file
\stoptext
```

Selected "ConTeXt (LuaTeX)" from dropdown menu.
Clicked on "Typeset"

The output at the Console this

```
resolvers       | formats | executing runner 'run luatex format': /usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-darwin/luatex --jobname="Untitled" --fmt=/Users/andre-penteado.dti/Library/texlive/2020/texmf-var/luatex-cache/context/a86c089b384a3076dc514ba966a1fac9/formats/luatex/cont-en.fmt --lua=/Users/andre-penteado.dti/Library/texlive/2020/texmf-var/luatex-cache/context/a86c089b384a3076dc514ba966a1fac9/formats/luatex/cont-en.lui cont-yes.mkiv --c:autogenerate --c:currentrun=1 --c:fulljobname="./Untitled.ctx" --c:input="./Untitled.ctx" --c:kindofrun=1 --c:maxnofruns=9 --c:synctex="1" --c:texmfbinpath="/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-darwin"
Could not undump 1 4-byte item(s): <fd:3>: unexpected end of file.
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020) 
 system commands enabled.
mtx-context     | fatal error: return code: 256
```

The same error occurs when typesetting the file on Teminal

```
context file.ctx
```

Here is what i tried before posting this question:

Online searches trying to find something helpful:

1. mtx-context     | fatal error: return code: 256
2. Could not undump 1 4-byte item(s): <fd:3>: unexpected end of file.
3. mactex context luatex fatal error: return code: 256
4. mactex context luatex unexpected end of file
5. Searched also here for similar questions without any luck

I hope this is not a duplicated question.

The steps I did is:

- Installed using Homebrew (brew install --cask mactex) (first install)
- Reinstalled using Homebrew (brew reinstall mactex)
- Uninstalled using Homebrew (brew uninstall mactex)
- Downloaded MacTex.pkg from [MacTex site](https://www.tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html)
- Installed MacTex.pkg (current installation)

Couldn't find any solution ... the error is still there :-(

Enviroment info:

- Hardware: MacBook Pro 16'' 2019
- OS: 10.15.6 (19G2021)

I have also have MacTeX installed in another MacBook Pro (macOS High Sierra) and everything works fine.

Could it be that it is a macOS-Catalina-only error?

I just couldn't figure out what is going on. Any help is very appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Have you updated you distribution? There have been many updates since MacTeX-2020 and TeX Live 2020 became available.

Comment: Try regenerating the format (`context --make`) and deleting the font cache.

Comment: Try using `mtxrun --script context --autogenerate --synctex=1 file.cts`.

Comment: I tried ```context --make``` and it now works. :D
I also reinstalled mactex with Homebrew and it seams to work there too.
Thanks for the help. Have a nice day you all.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was fixed by regenerating the format files.